# Essentially Bounded Functions

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Show that if $f$ is Lipschitz then $f^{\prime}$ is  essentially bounded.

Help me in this exercise.

Comment: @Ian It exists a.e. by [Rademacher's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly just using definitions.  To show that $f’$ is essentially bounded, you must show that there exists a constant $C \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ so that 
$\{x:|\,f'(x)\,| > C\}$ has measure $0$.  Since $f$ is Lipschitz, there exists $C \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ so that 
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C\,|x-y|$$ for all $x$ and $y$. 
The same $C$ satisfies the definition of essentially bounded: at any $x$ where $f$ is differentiable, we have
$$|\,f’(x)\,| = \left| \,\lim_{y \to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \, \right|.$$
Since absolute value is a continuous function, the absolute value of a limit is the limit of the absolute value.  Hence, this becomes
$$|\,f’(x)\,| = \lim_{y \to x}\left|\,\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \,\right| \leq \lim_{y \to x} \frac{C \, |y-x|}{|y-x|} = C.$$